# Wrong encoding in Spring portlet via ajax(Liferay)

Tags: java, ajax, spring, liferay, portlet

Have a simple Spring MVC portlet, and from one of portal pages I have to load content using AJAX.

```
  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:ajaxlink,
        data:"lastnumber=" + lastnumber,
        cache:false,
        success:function (htmlanswer) {

            $("#cityspeakcontent").append(htmlanswer);


        }
    });
```

The result of request is in wrong encoding: "Ð–ÐÐ’ÐžÐ ÐžÐÐžÐš, Ð¶Ð°Ð²Ñ€Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ðº Ð¼. Ð¿Ð¾Ð"(must be utf-8)

At jsp page i have

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Also tried to add filter:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

There is no result.

And when in ajax request I add

```
contentType: "charset=utf-8"
```

there is an Exception generating by Liferay with very large stacktrace=) (As I understand Exception in doFilter method of com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter)

WTF i'm doing wrong?

Comment: anybody has any idea on this issue? I have encountered the exact same situation and still looking for a clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the serveResource() method, did you try setting:

```
resourceResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```